# how to knew the order of views that build above table in presto

Tags: view, presto

I have table "prod.refrence_type" I create view above it like :

```
create view s_per.refrence_type as select * from prod.refrence_type ;
```

then I create view above s_per.refrence_type :

```
create view s_per.final_type as select * from s_per.refrence_type ;
```

is there are any way to  knew from presto for given table name what is the order of views created ?
the excepted output is  :
**prod.refrence_type,s_per.refrence_type,s_per.final_type**

what I try :
I can get only on the direct view that we build above table using information_schema.views :

```
SELECT table_catalog,table_schema,table_name,view_owner,regexp_replace(view_definition,'\n',' ') FROM information_schema.views where table_name  LIKE '%prod.refrence_type%'
```

so i can get **s_per.refrence_type** but i can not get **s_per.final_type** , is there are any direct way for a given table name to get the views in the orders that they build on presto ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to have something like a graph or order, view b is based on view a and view a is based on table c. And you want to know all views that are directly or indirectly based on table c?

Comment: @Philipp Johannis yes correct that exactly what I want